# Switching between docker tags

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have an apache,wsgi based python application on ubuntu machine. Application is inside a docker container. Developer fix issue 1, deploy it and gives to tester. Developer fixed issue 2 but can`t deploy since tester is still testing issue 1. Is it possible if developer can create tags in docker image and can switch between them ? He can have 2 different versions of code in two tags or commits, can switch between them whenever he or tester wants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each time you commit a container you will get a different image ID.
Each of this images can be tagged independently.
Example:

```
docker images
REPOSITORY     TAG         IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE                                                                                

python         1.0         e0122ddbfbc5        23 hours ago        100 MB
python         latest      e0122ddbfbc5        23 hours ago        100 MB
```

Change 1:

```
docker commit python:1.1
docker images
REPOSITORY     TAG         IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE                                                                                

python         1.0         e0122ddbfbc5        23 hours ago        100 MB
python         latest      e0122ddbfbc5        23 hours ago        100 MB
python         1.1         ba130ccb3f66        1 minute ago        101 MB
```

Change 2:

```
docker commit python:1.2
docker images
REPOSITORY     TAG         IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
python         1.0         e0122ddbfbc5        23 hours ago        100 MB
python         latest      e0122ddbfbc5        23 hours ago        100 MB
python         1.1         ba130ccb3f66        10 minute ago        101 MB
python         1.2         946baf236fcc        1 minute ago        101 MB
```

Once accepted you can tag the image as latest:

```
docker tag python:1.1 python:latest
```

or

```
 docker tag python:1.2 python:latest
```